# Why do browsers render rgba differently on OSX?

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, alpha, rgba

I was trying to code up some color manipulation code and was stuck for a long time with alpha, then I (2 hours later) realized browsers render rgba differently.

I created this test: http://jsbin.com/adekez/2/
add /edit to look at the code

Here are the results in 4 browsers in OSX Lion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9wSw.jpg

That is an element with a background of rgba(0,0,0,0.5) on top of white.

My hex calculator says: FF÷2 = 7F.8 which means

Safari at #808080 is correct
Firefox at #7F7F7F is off by 1
Opera at #7E7E7E is off by 2
Chrome at #929292 is way off

What's going here, is this a bug in Chrome or do I just not know about colors (true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First off

Well, actually Safari **and** Firefox are both correct:
`0xFF = 255`, `255 / 2 = 127.5`. So `128` may be correct (`0x80`), but also `127` (`0x7F`) - depending on the rounding convention of the browser.

### Explantion of the issue

These are rounding issues. I don't quite get *why* there are rounding issues, since 0.5 is representable in binary numbers without precision loss, but there are, in fact rounding issues:

Opera:
[image: Opera Screenshot]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

When I checked in chrome & safari, But I got exact same rgba color #808080 in both. Let us know which browser version you are using.

[image: rgba alpha value issue]